# My angular compiler is creating a ghost extra css rule

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-compiler

It appears the angular compiler is generating me a ghost rule for a scss selector '.features-icon-box h3' is generating .features-icon-box h3,.features-icon-box.h3

I have a regular website using Angular 15 and some (not too many) extra dependencies to have a nice website, is just an index with some sections on it with their styles. Among those styles i have a rule set:

```
.features-icon-box {
  //styles
  h3 {
    //nice-styles
  }
}
```

when i run my code, the compiler happens to generate this:
`.features-icon-box h3,.features-icon-box .h3{//nice-styles}`

it generates two rules one for h3 tag and one for .h3 class, it happens i don't have any rule for `.features-icon-box .h3`, i've searched my entire project folder for it as many times as possible, i also searched inside my node_modules and nothing. I asked around and it could be some of my dependencies having some rule for it, searched already and none is generating such a rule, as a matter of fact if i remove the original rule the compiler won't generate the '.features-icon-box .h3' one, so is definetly this scss style that's generating the extra rule i dont want to. Is this a bug on angular compiler or what could i possible have wrong for that simple rule is generating an extra one for .h3 classes too?

Comment: I haven't tried the old trusty of creating a new project just with that style but that's a lot of work to do i'm trying to avoid, also i'm using ng-bootstrap 14.1.1, i dont think is that either, idk

Comment: Cannot reproduce this in my Angular project...

Comment: @JSONDerulo let me see if i can replicate in stackbliz or smtg, never done that before